# How to count number of tuples in a relation (Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I get the following error when I try to count the number of users in the users table. Connection is up and running and I can fetch other data, but the issue is specific to counting. `id` is the primary key for the relation. Documentation suggests this is the way to correctly use count.

Error

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "users.id" must
>   appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

#### Count the number of users

```
req.users.findAll({
      attributes: { include: [[req.sequelize.fn('COUNT', req.sequelize.col('username')), 'users']] }
    });
```

#### Model definition

```
req.users = sequelize.define("users", Users);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
req.users.findAndCountAll()
```

Is the better option that works. It returns a `promise` with an object containing `rows`, `count`.

#### How I got the count

```
const count = await req.users.findAndCountAll().then(result => {
  if (result.count > 0) throw new Error()
});
```